# KeyBoard not shown (does not respond) when EditText is selected in android fragment

Tags: android-fragments

here is my fragment class:

```
public class PrayerTimes extends Fragment {
     EditText Lat;
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    InflaterView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_prayer_times, container, false);

    Lat = (EditText) InflaterView.findViewById(R.id.LatitudeEdit); 

    Lat.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }

public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {   
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    return InflaterView;
}
```

when the Fragment loads,  and The EDitText (Lat) is selected (Get Focused ) no KeyBoard is shown . How To Show The KeyBoard?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
Lat.clearFocus();
```

immediately after the line:

```
Lat = (EditText) InflaterView.findViewById(R.id.LatitudeEdit);
```